# PyCharm hint that "foo" can be undefined, but how?

Tags: python, for-loop, pycharm, undefined, break

I am working with Python in PyCharm and came across a weird hint IMO.

Following a simple example:

```
myNumbers = [0, 1, 2]
for val in myNumbers:
    if val == 1:
        foo = 1
        break
    else:
        foo = 2
print "Foo is: ", foo
```

In the last line, for variable "foo" PyCharm says "Name 'foo' can be undefined".

I'm wondering why and how? In which case could that happen?

I know that for particularly this snippet "foo" is always 1 and the else branch is never executed, but that is insignificant right now.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This code works on with normal text editor using python2.7.16 (gcc(8.3.0) linux). You too try it out. If you have Python3, dont forget to change your print statement!!

Comment: You only assign to `foo` inside a `for` loop - which could potentially execute zero times, thus leaving `foo` undefined.  The loop does execute at least once in your specific case, but that's something that can't always be proven.

Comment: Note that if you inline the numbers (`for val in [0, 1, 2]`) the hint will go away, as in this case PyCharm apparently has enough information to detect that the lookp will be executed at least once.

Comment: > The loop does execute at least once in your specific case, but that's something that can't always be proven.

When is that the case?

And yes, putting the list into the for loop instead of the identifier helped to disappear the hint.
And why is the block quote not working? :D

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is because foo is defined within the loop. If your list myNumbers would be empty, then foo would be undefined, as the loop would have zero iterations. So I guess, when giving the hint for foo to be undefined, PyCharm is (probably deliberately) ignoring the definition of myNumbers above the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`myNumbers = [0, 1, 2]
for val in myNumbers:
    if val == 1:
        foo = 1
        break
    else:
        foo = 2
print( "Foo is: ", foo)`

you forget the ( )

it says foo cant be undefined, because you cant just write "foo" in an code

you need to say what it should do with it. :)

so: remind:

print()

Comment: it has nothing to do with python 2/3

Answer (score -2):

It is probably Python 3+ and you missed the parentheses in print() function.

```
myNumbers = [0, 1, 2]
for val in myNumbers:
 if val == 1:
    foo = 1
    break
 else:
    foo = 2
print("Foo is: ", foo)
```

Comment: it has nothing to do with python 2/3